# Dynamically pass in type to MemoryLayout<T> in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create a function like this:

```
func getStride(_ type: T.Type) {
  return MemoryLayout<type>.stride
}
```

But it [doesn't work](https://medium.com/developermind/generics-in-swift-4-4f802cd6f53c).

I would like to be able to call it like this:

```
getStride(Bool) //=> stride value
```

If not that, then perhaps this:

```
getStride(Bool.self)
```

Wondering if anything like this is possible.

Comment: Your "doesn't work" link points to a general article about generics in Swift, is that intended?

Comment: Yeah I looked through it but generics are a new concept and I wasn't able to glean it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a *generic* function, then you can refer to `MemoryLayout<T>` with the same type that was passed to the function:

```
func getStride<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Int {
    return MemoryLayout<T>.stride
}

print(getStride(Bool.self)) // 1
print(getStride(Double.self)) // 8
```